# Плавающий баг в JavaScript

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

Столкнулся с необычным для меня багом (Я назвал его плавающим).

Суть в том что у меня всплывает ошибка `TypeError: document.getElementById(...) is null` и всплывает она через раз.

Якобы элемента info на странице нету, хотя он есть! :)

Я пробовал словить проблему отладчиком, но так и не понял в чем проблема.

Вот код в котором я обращаюсь к элементу 'info':

```
function profileRequest() {
  var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

  xhr.open('GET', 'https://api.github.com/users/ProstoJohn', false);
  xhr.send();

    var data = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
  console.log(data);
    var divUser = document.createElement('div');

    divUser.innerHTML = "<div class='user anim aslide'>Логин: <a href='" + data.html_url + "' target='_blank'>@" + data.login + "</a> <img id='userimg' src='" + data.avatar_url + "' width='125'> <br> Email: " + data.email + "</div><br>";
    document.getElementById('info').appendChild(divUser);
}
```

Посмотреть код полностью можно тут: http://cake.myfactoryhub.com/

Буду благодарен за любую помощь...

Comment: Пробовал смотреть в других браузерах? У меня в опере ни разу эта ошибка не возникла.

Comment: @Sapphiron, Сори залил не ту версию, вот щас залил проблемную ;-(

Comment: ну так нету у вас там этого элемента когда вы скрипт вызываете. Поставьте там breakpoint и сами увидите - когда сработает страница еще пустая, т.к. шаблон templates/profile.html еще не подгрузился. script.js, 43 строка - после этой строчки надо вызывать profileRequest(), тогда проблем не будет

Comment: @ProstoJohn У вас функция loadPage загружает с сервера содержимое для `<div id=content>` И когда нажимаешь на "главная" в него загружается пустота. А в других режимах именно внутри, вместо этой пустоты лежит `div id=info`

Comment: @BOPOH, ну вообще когда я вызываю `profileRequest()` когда элемент уже появился. Можете посмотреть, я вызываю ее в конце `function loadPage(url) {...}`

Comment: @ProstoJohn, я уже посмотрел, поэтому и говорю - именно в этом у вас и проблема. Как видите, браузер со мною полностью согласен. Пока вы этого не поймете - у вас будет ошибка. А причина в том, что запрос вы шлете асинхронный, т.е. ответ (а значит и info) придут когда-то "потом", но вы сразу же шлете запрос на добавление в этот еще не существующий info чего-то там. Если успеет загрузиться шаблон пока не потребуется info - будет работать как надо. Если шаблон не успеет загрузиться - будет ошибка. Поэтому profileRequest надо делать после того, как шаблон подгрузится, т.е. после 43 строки

Comment: @BOPOH, да ваш ответ помог, можете оформить ответ?

Comment: 1) *Synchronous XMLHttpRequest on the main thread is deprecated because of its detrimental effects to the end user's experience. For more help, check https://xhr.spec.whatwg.org/.* (это про profileRequest) 2) откройте [эту страницу](http://cake.myfactoryhub.com/profile) (а ведь надо чтобы работало) 3) `console.log(data);` можно убрать 4) а зачем ручками отправлять запросы? почему не хотите готовые библиотеки использовать? тот же jquery? 5) я ответы редко пишу )) сами можете ответить и плюсы получить )

Comment: @BOPOH, нет уж. ответил - пиши ответ :-D

Comment: @BOPOH, Cпасибо за ответ, /profile не работает ибо у меня на ноуте стоит node и настроен сервер на обработку страниц. С XHR я разберусь :). А Console.log() был для теста, уже убрал. Мне нельзя использовать jquery ибо я щас учу чистый js и уже когда выучу буду использовать что душе будет пригодно, ибо буду понимать суть работы нативного javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> А проблема в том, что запрос вы шлете асинхронный, т.е. ответ (а
>   значит и info) придут когда-то "потом", но вы сразу же шлете запрос на
>   добавление в этот еще не существующий info чего-то там. Если успеет
>   загрузиться шаблон пока не потребуется info - будет работать как надо.
>   Если шаблон не успеет загрузиться - будет ошибка. Поэтому
>   profileRequest надо делать после того, как шаблон подгрузится, т.е.
>   после 43 строки

**Спасибо за ответ [BOPOH](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/5079/bopoh)**